# Truncate within helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following helper in Rails 3:

```
def other_contact_info(shop = false)
  shop = shop ? shop : @shop
  email = mail_to(shop.email, "Email", :encode => "javascript") if shop.web.present?
  web = link_to(shop.web, truncate(shop.web), :target => "_blank") if shop.web.present?
  raw [shop.contact, email, web].select(&:present?).join(" · ")
end
```

The `truncate` doesn't do anything. How can I fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second argument in link_to is the URL. I think you want truncate to be on the first argument which is the link text displayed to the user:

```
link_to(truncate(shop.web), __URL__, :target => "_blank")
```